# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not called for all expected orientation modes

Tags: iphone

I have a UIViewController added to a window and my app is configured to support Portrait and LandscapeLeft orientations in the Info.plist file.

I'm holding the device in Landscape Left and after my view loads, I see two calls to '`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`'. However, both times the method is called, the value of '`toInterfaceOrientation`' is always '`UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`'.

I was expecting one call to Portrait and at least another for '`UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`' since that is how I'm currently holding the device.

The Controller's view xib is configured to with Portrait mode to load the view but I thought I'd be asked on what orientations are supported besides Portrait.

Any ideas why I don't get two different orientation modes passed into '`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your view controller inside another view controller?

Orientation changes only get to the first VC in the response chain, then the propagation of the messages is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if you fail to retain your view controller.  So if your app delegate has

```
 UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
 [self.window addSubview: vc.view];
```

then under Automatic Reference Counting, vc will be deallocated shortly after the above code executes.  Therefore, there will be no autorotation.  To fix this, assign vc to a strong ivar.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was completely stumped on this one :)